# android - Firebase return null value from datasnapshot Why?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having some touble with the following code snipped:

```
mCevap.child(post_key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void  onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        size = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();   
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
viewHolder.setCount(size);
```

The size returns null but I don't understand why. I want to pass count values to recyclerview.

Comment: Post your database structure and what mCevap is

Comment: Here is what I want to return 'size'. But you are constantly turning to zero. If I print it with 'Toast', it is reflected normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. This means that the order in which your code is execute is not what you're likely expecting. You can most easily see this by adding a few log statements to the code:

```
System.out.println("Before addListenerForSingleValueEvent");
mCevap.child(post_key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void  onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println("In onDataChange");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
System.out.println("After addListenerForSingleValueEvent");
```

The output of this is:

> Before addListenerForSingleValueEvent
>
> After addListenerForSingleValueEvent
>
> In onDataChange

This is probably not what you expected! The data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. And instead of waiting for it to return (which would cause an "Application Not Responding" dialog), the method continues. Then when the data is available, your `onDataChange` is invoked.

To make the program work, you need to move the code that needs the data **into** the `onDataChange` method:

```
mCevap.child(post_key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void  onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println("size ="+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: How can I transfer it to TextView which is also found in RecycleView.