# Firebase Database query users in a loop

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, android-architecture-components

For example, I have a list of issues. Each issue has owner uid. By this uid, I should find needed users and display his name and photo. I do it with help architecture component ViewModel:

```
 issues.forEach {
        IssueRepository().getIssueOwner(it.owner).observe(this, Observer {

        })
    }
```

getIssueOwner method:

```
fun getIssueOwner(uid: String): MutableLiveData<UserEntity> {
    val user: MutableLiveData<UserEntity> = MutableLiveData()
    val usersReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("users")
    val query = usersReference.orderByKey().equalTo(uid).limitToFirst(1)
    query.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
        }

        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
            if (dataSnapshot == null) {
                return
            }
            dataSnapshot.children.forEach {
                val name = it.child("displayName").value
                user.postValue(UserEntity(name))
            }

        }
    })
    return user
}
```

But I'm sure that this approach is not correct. Could you please give me an advice how I should build the architecture of my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
val query = usersReference.orderByKey().equalTo(uid).limitToFirst(1)
```

Gives exactly the same results as this much simpler:

```
val userReference = usersReference.child(uid)
```

The only difference between the two is that the first snippet gives you a snapshot with a list of one item, while the second snippet gives you a snapshot with just the item.

```
val userReference = usersReference.child(uid)
userReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError?) {
        throw error.toException() // don't ignore errors
    }

    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()
            val name = dataSnapshot.child("displayName").value
            user.postValue(UserEntity(name))
        }
    }
})
```

Note that you still can't return a user from the `getIssueOwner` method. This is because data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, and by the time your `return` statement is executed, the `onDataChange` hasn't been called yet.

I recommend you read a few of these previous question on that topic to learn more about dealing with the asynchronous nature of Firebase (and most of the modern web):

- [android - Firebase return value from datasnapshot Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121020/android-firebase-return-value-from-datasnapshot-why)
- [Querying data from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576441/querying-data-from-firebase)
- [Wait Firebase async retrive data in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723139/wait-firebase-async-retrive-data-in-android)
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)

Comment: Thanks a lot, maybe you know a good way how to perform JOIN query in Android, please help me)